# Access query complexity: layered calculations

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to run some complex calculations (similar to a limit) on data stored in Access. I'm able to perform the calculation by using layered/nested queries, where each expression is based on the result of the last. My problem is that on about the 9th iteration I get a "Query is too complex" error. My understanding is this is because Access is limited in the number of sub-queries that can be performed simultaneously. Is there an alternative to using AS in the SELECT statement that would allow me to perform more iterations in the same query? I've tried to simplify down my SQL to better show what I am doing (ignore the actual calculation being performed in the example).

```
SELECT Tbl_1.VarA, Tbl_1.VarB,
(VarA^2*([VarA]+[VarB])/2) AS EQ1,
(VarA^2*([VarA]+[EQ1])/2) AS EQ2
FROM Tbl_1
```

My current work around is to save the last iteration to a table and then run a second query on that value. I feel this is really bad practice though.

I've tried, unsuccessfully, to: 
(1) base a second query on the first 
(2) replace constant variables with their values 
(3) nest the equation, i.e.
(VarA^2*([VarA]+(VarA^2*([VarA]+[VarB])/2))/2) AS EQ2

I apologize in advance if I'm not referring to something properly, as I'm relatively new.

Comment: Have you considered a user defined function?

Comment: Hadn't referenced functions in VBA within my queries' sql before. Mainly just used it for front end. Worked just like referencing functions in other parts of the VBA. This accomplished what I needed and seems to run considerably faster as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding calculated columns to your table, and use those expressions for EQ1 and EQ2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff945943.aspx

Comment: I should have specified, I'm working in 2007 and have to make it back compatible to 2003 to work with other programs. Is there a way to perform the same functionality in the older versions?